# How to create a simple mysql base treeview in php

Tags: php, mysql, treeview, nodes

I have spent a lots of times to create a really easy to use and simple treeview in PHP that retrieve nodes information from MySQL database but nothing useful and none complex solution till now.

Please tell me how to do that if you know the right solution. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Sorry, the treeview should be able to support RTL direction "right to left".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right solution is [jsTree](http://www.jstree.com/). It is a javascript based, cross browser tree component
with rtl direction support. :D